# Is there an Ubuntu alternative for Windows snipping tool?

Tags: apt

Is there an Ubuntu alternative for the Windows snipping tool?

Comment: What is a "windows snippet tool" and what does it do?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is called screenshot. Please search for it in the dash!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple different screenshot tools you can use. On 22.04 there should be a default and interactive [screenshot utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html).

Press the following key on your keyboard (or launch **"take a screenshot"** from the **Activities** menu):

<kbd>PRINT</kbd> = launch the screenshot utility

From here, you can use the following keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>S</kbd> = Select area
- <kbd>C</kbd> = Capture screen
- <kbd>W</kbd> = Capture window
- <kbd>P</kbd> = Toggle between show and hide pointer
- <kbd>V</kbd> = Toggle between screenshot and screencast
- <kbd>ENTER</kbd> = Capture, also activated by Space or Ctrl+C

You can also use the following keyboard shortcuts any time without first launching the screenshot utility:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PRINT</kbd> = screenshot the current window

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>PRINT</kbd> = clip a selection of the screen similar to snippet

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> = start or stop a screen video recording or "screencast"

Or you can use an alternative screenshot tool. If you are using the default Ubuntu desktop, you would probably want to use `gnome-screenshot` and you can either install it through the software center or you can run the following commands to install this app:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-screenshot
```

Then, look for gnome screenshot in your dash and launch the app. It will give you options like if you want to take a selection from the screen which is more like snippet or if you want to simply take an entire screenshot.

Aside from Gnome Screenshot, another good option is Kazam.

Comment: You can also use Gimp to take a screenshot. From Gimp, select **File** > **Create** > **Screenshot**.